# Moved /home to separate partition, installed 64-bit Xubuntu, can't log in but everything looks fine

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, login, home-directory, fstab

So after trying to install Steam on my old installation of Ubuntu, I realised that I had been using 32-bit Lubuntu on my 64-bit machine. So I decided to move my `/home` directory to a separate partition (`sda6`) and install a 64-bit Xubuntu in the place of the old Lubuntu (`sda4`), and then do the whole `fstab` editing to designate `sda6` as the `/home` partition... so I could use a 64-bit OS with my old files.

What ended up happening was I got Xubuntu to install, but it created its own `/home` directory and was using that. I could access my old files in the old `/home`, but Xubuntu wouldn't touch it. So I tried to fix that and ended up screwing up the whole thing and leaving it for a week.

I came back today and after some article reading, reinstalled Xubuntu, but this time at the manual partitioning step I designated `sda6` as `/home`, and `sda4` as `/` and ticked the box to format it.

That brings us to where I am now. I can't log into my user account! In the virtual console `tty1` I can, and I made a temporary user account, but after going back to the graphical interface, I can't log into that account either. I'm currently on the guest account, which works perfectly fine.

Help me please! Any input is appreciated. :)

Comment: Reinstall again but this time use "something else" and explicitly define your current / (root) and tick format and then select /home and DO NOT tick format.

Comment: "I came back today and after some article reading, reinstalled xubuntu, but this time at the manual partitioning step I designated sda6 as /home, and sda4 as / and ticked the box to format it. " <--i tried it! still doesnt work..I could try again?